# How to get specific format using hexdump or xxd?

Tags: linux, hexdump, xxd

I require the hexdumps of a number of files in a specific format:

```
00000000 4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00
```

However, using hexdump or xxd I can only manage to get the above with a colon after the address and the ASCII text to the right of it, e.g.:

```
00000000: 4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 
MZ..............
```

I got the above using the command

```
xxd -g 1 -u filename
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Any ideas?` - yeah, take it to superuser.com where it belongs, this question isn't about programming.

Comment: Or to https://unix.stackexchange.com. And the most probably answer will be "read the manpage".

Comment: `od -t x1 filename`

Comment: @Shawn i got some extra text at the end when running that command, https://i.imgur.com/qTGfhFj.png

Comment: @ICEpower I added a bit to my answer, including how to get upper-case output if wanted and how to get rid of that last line that `od` always prints if you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

[`hexdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) is able to produce this output, and provides much more options, once you figure out the somewhat arcane, yet powerful, format syntax.

```
$ hexdump -v -e '"%08_ax" 16/1 " %02X" "\n"' en.gif 
00000000 47 49 46 38 37 61 10 00 0A 00 A1 03 00 CC 00 00
00000010 44 44 CC FF FF FF FF BB 66 2C 00 00 00 00 10 00
00000020 0A 00 00 02 25 8C 20 61 A8 97 BA 92 8B 10 BA CB
00000030 AA 45 FC 59 01 82 C0 18 96 E3 89 A6 64 79 AC 6C
00000040 E5 74 DA 26 D6 F3 84 67 41 01 00 3B
```

The format in detail:

- `"%08_ax"` is the offset in hexadecimal, 8 digits with leading zeroes.
- `16/1 " %02X"` displays 16 bytes per iteration (line), one byte per block, each block formatted as 2 uppercase hexadecimal digits with leading zeroes and preceeding space.
- `"\n"` finishes each iteration (line) with a newline.

Answer (score 2):

`od` is one way:

After creating an example file via

```
perl -e 'print map { chr hex } @ARGV' 4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 > foo.bin
```

getting a hex dump of it:

```
$ od -Ax -t x1 foo.bin
0000000 4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00
0000010
```

The key here is the `-t FORMAT` argument. In the format, `x` uses base 16, and `1` means to print one byte per block. The `-Ax` says to print out the offsets in base 16 instead of the default base 8.

It does print out the offset of the end of the file as the last line, but that's trivial to get rid of with `head -n -1` if not needed. There doesn't seem to be a way to make it use upper-case hex digits, but that's also easily fixable if you prefer them:

```
$ od -Ax -t x1 foo.bin | head -n -1 | tr a-f A-F
000000 4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't need the end offset and wanted upper-case hex digits too, so thanks for adding those!